# how to redirect to an HTML page from PHP processing page

Tags: php, html

I'm not a PHP GURU, yet, but need a little assistance.

I have an HTML page the has a form going to a PHP page to process the data from the form.

That's all fine and dandy, but when I hit submit, the login page (HTML) simply flashes, the database gets updated, and my redirect simply spits out the HTML raw code into the RESPONSE.

I want to have the new page appear, not have the code spit out in a RESPONSE TEXT in the console.log.

Here's what I have in the PHP:

```
header('Location: pageAfterLogin.html');
exit();
```

This doesn't show the page but does nothing.

The index.html page, the php page and the pageAfterLogin.html are all in the same domain.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Here's the form processing PHP page:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("somehost.com", "username", "password", "dbname");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// define variables and set to empty values
$fname = $lname = $email = $phone = $address = $aptste = $city = $state = $zipcode = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
    $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
    $address = test_input($_POST["address"]);
    $aptste = test_input($_POST["aptste"]);
    $city = test_input($_POST["city"]);
    $state = test_input($_POST["state"]);
    $zipcode = test_input($_POST["zipcode"]);
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstName, lastName, email, phone, address, aptste, city, state, zipcode, datCreated, newUser)
VALUES ('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[address]',"
        . "'$_POST[aptste]','$_POST[city]','$_POST[state]','$_POST[zipcode]','".getdate()."',1)";

if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_close($con);


header('Location: pageAfterLogin.html');
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Define "but does nothing"

Comment: You mentioned console.log  Are you making this login request via AJAX?

Comment: Are there any contents that is sent before calling the header function ?

Comment: `header()` should be above any browser output.

Comment: It's more likely the script is existing before it could reach the header function. Make sure there are no `die` or `exit` functions before it, and enable error display, so you can check if some internal error is causing this issue

Comment: @HalfCrazed No necessarily. You should not just echo or output anything before it.

Comment: Is the extension on the PHP file `.php`?  If not, you'll either have to rename it, or configure a `.html` file to run php.  Like [this](http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm).

Comment: With respect to John conde's comment: Define "but does nothing".  The processForm.php works to the fact that it's inserting into the database table.  But the next page is not showing or being redirected.  The main login page simply flashes, the fields clear out and that's pretty much it.  I'll send over the two pages for more clarity.  Thanks, John.

Comment: TO: Mike Brant: Yes, I'm making an AJAX request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You (or a library you use) are most likely echo'ing something before you are sending your headers. Headers must go above anything else.